# MS Access - insert into takes more time when I'm looping statements

Tags: sql, ms-access, optimization, sharepoint

I'm working in the Access which is connected to the SharePoint list. I have code to insert the values into SharePoint list from notepad where I have multiple lines like here:
`INSERT INTO  SharePointList ( [Column 1].[Value] ) VALUES(489) WHERE SharePointList.[Column 2] LIKE '*something*';`

I do not know why is it happening but the first file with 5 rows is executing in ~ 2min but the next file is taking much more time around ~5.5min. Time is increasing with every iteration. Do you have any ideas how I can clear cache (or anything) to reduce time as it was in the first-run?  Maybe the code is not optimized?

Code which I'm using in VBA:

```
Sub SQLScripts()

Dim vSql       As Variant
Dim vSqls      As Variant
Dim strSql     As String
Dim intF       As Integer

Dim nextFile As Integer: nextFile  = 1
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double, FinishedLineIn As String
Dim filePath As String

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim fileStream As TextStream
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
For nextFile = 1 To 100

    intF = FreeFile()
    Open "C:\PATH\SQLCode " & nextFile & ".txt" For Input As #intF
    strSql = Input(LOF(intF), #intF)
    Close intF
    vSql = Split(strSql, ";")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    For Each vSqls In vSql
        StartTime = Timer
        CurrentDb.Execute vSqls
        SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
        FinishedLineIn = FinishedLineIn & Chr(10) & "Time needed: " & SecondsElapsed & Chr(10)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print "sql err" & Err.Descripiton & "-->"; vSqls
        End If
    Next
    filePath = "C:\PATH\ Completed SQLCode " & nextFile & ".txt"
    Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath)
    fileStream.WriteLine FinishedLineIn
Next nextFile
End Sub
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: wild card "like" command in your update, then a full table scan is going to occur on SharePoint.  If you have a index on that column you CAN use "Something*" but "*somthing*" (wild card on both sides cannot use any indexing). Inserts to SharePoint are already a VERY slow process - and that like command makes this all the worse. It not NOT all clear why or what that like criteria on a insert does anyway? Can't you remove the like? (or do the test in the text file before you import). I would simply remove that like command. However, it may not help.  I would try using a reocrdset in place of sql

Comment: Using a recordset sounds counter intuitive - but in this case it will run MUCH faster.